# Sound settings are missing

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I know there are tons of topics with that name, but I just can't make it work.
I had alsamixer from start and it didn't show me sound settings except for mixer itself.

I tried to install gnome control panel, and now when I right click on volume and choose "Volume control" settings, I don't get even alsamixer to appear. Instead I see 1 extra sound icon of gnome control panel, which when I right click on it shows me button "Sound preferences" while it opens just control panel without settings in it... What should I do?

This is what I have in control panel

[image]

Also... I have noise in my earplugs when I don't play music, I can't fix it either even though Power saving is false.

Answer (score 4):

Install gnome control center and pulseaudio again to fix this issue:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

If still doesn't fix your problem:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If after installing gnome-control-center you still have noise problem try to install pulseaudio:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Comment: The problem is, that I already tried to install gnome-control-center, I even tried reinstalling it. P.S. In fact, they are both installed .

Comment: Sadly, this didn't help either... I tried those ways too before making this post.

Comment: This woks for me. I have tried various ways of fixing this issue while I was trying to fix my bluetooth audio connection. OS: 16.04

Answer (score 1):

For those who only need to restore sound settings, the alternative is to install `unity-control-center` (you need to ensure  `gnome-control-center` is installed before doing this), e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

that works in Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04 LTS , should also work in latest version